# AJAX validation for Html::active...() fields

Tags: yii2

I'm using `ActiveForm` for my model form. However, for a couple of fields, instead of using `$form->field(...)->dropDownList()` where `$form = ActiveForm::begin()` to display the field, I use `Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'attribute')` and for the corresponding attribute, I have a validation rule (inside the model). I've also enabled `enableAjaxValidation` and `enableClientValidation` in the form. I notice that while the AJAX validation is triggered for all fields created with the `$form->field()` method, my custom `Html::activeDropDownList()` fields do not trigger the validation (I can see those excluded from the `yiiActiveForm()` javascript function call in the generated page source). How am I going to automatically trigger the AJAX validation for these fields too?

Comment: Show specific code, maybe usage of `activeDropDownList` is not required, and you can achieve the same for example with using `$form->field` and configuring `template`.

Comment: Do you set client validation? example: <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'id' => 'someform'
]); ?>

Comment: @Fortran I do, I've already stated this in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I think you should use ActiveForm for all fields to make validation work as expected. Why don't you use `$form->field(...)->dropDownList()`?

You may write your own validator for this custom fields (some of fields will be validated by ActiveForm, some with your handler), but it's bad practice.